# parse large XML in loop python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, xml-parsing, lxml

I would like to parse XML (~1GB) with the following structure:

```xml
<Publication creationDateTime="04-AUG-2019 05:22:07">
  <holds>
    <hold>
      <recordType>Standard</recordType>
      <isEnroute>true</isEnroute>
      <holdName>NANLANG</holdName>
      <holdTime>10</holdTime>
      <inbound>
        <courseValue>170</courseValue>
      </inbound>
      <min>
        <altitude>7874</altitude>
      </min>
    </hold>
    <hold>
      <recordType>Standard</recordType>
      <holdName>ZILINA LOM</holdName>
      <holdTime>10</holdTime>
      <inbound>
        <courseValue>243</courseValue>
      </inbound>
      <max>
        <isFlightLevel>true</isFlightLevel>
        <altitude>85</altitude>
      </max>
      <min>
        <altitude>4500</altitude>
      </min>
    </hold>
  </holds>
</Publication>
```

I have cleared that the most efficient way is to use [lxml.etree iterparse method](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-hiperfparse/).

I need to parse every tag to the variable and then insert into DB.
The thing is that I didn't catch the way I can iterate through 'head' tag (e.g. hold) and insert to database, my code sample is below:

```
class Avia:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in kwargs.keys():
            self.__dict__[attr] = kwargs[attr]

context = ET.iterparse('test.xml')

def xml_fast_iter(context):
    for event, elem in context:
        if elem.tag == 'holdName':
            hold_name = elem.text
        elif elem.tag == 'holdTime':
            hold_time = elem.text
        elif elem.tag == 'courseValue':
            course = float(elem.text)
        elif elem.tag == 'isEnroute':
            hold_enr = elem.text
        # ...

        elem.clear()
        for ancestor in elem.xpath('ancestor-or-self::*'):
            if ancestor.tag == 'min':
                bottom = alt
            if ancestor.tag == 'max':
                top = alt

            while ancestor.getprevious() is not None:
                del ancestor.getparent()[0]

        if elem.tag == 'hold':
            hold_type = 'TER'
            if hold_enr:
                hold_type = 'ENR'
            outbound = course + 180 if course + 180 < 360 else course - 180
            holdPattern = Avia(name=hold_name, time=hold_time, course=course, outbound=outbound, type=hold_type, bottom=bottom, top=top)
            prop_dict = holdPattern.__dict__
            print(prop_dict)
    del context
```

When trying to print, I obviously get `hold_type = 'ENR'` for second object because `hold_enr` is true for the 1st object and it is not changed while the second hasn't this key... When trying to assign `None` to all of the variables after `for event, elem in context:` I'll get the all values=None except the last one because they are looping over the every element.

What is the proper way to parse all the keys and initialize the object? Maybe my way is totally wrong?

Is it correct to assign None to variables **after the initialization**?
(then hold_type is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also listen for the `'start'` event and initialize your variables at this point.

Working with a `dict` that you can pass to `Avia()` as-is is convenient, so is using a generator function (i.e. `yield hold`).

```
def xml_fast_iter(xmlfile):
    context = ET.iterparse(xmlfile, events=('start', 'end'))

    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'start':
            if elem.tag == 'hold':
                hold = {
                    'name': 'define',
                    'time': 'all',
                    'course': 'defaults',
                    'outbound': 'here',
                    'type': 'TER',
                    'bottom': '',
                    'top': '',
                }
                max = {
                    'altitude': 0
                }
                min = {
                    'altitude': 0
                }
            if elem.tag == 'max':
                minmax = max
            if elem.tag == 'min':
                minmax = min
        else:
            if elem.tag == 'holdName':
                hold['name'] = elem.text
            elif elem.tag == 'holdTime':
                hold['time'] = elem.text
            elif elem.tag == 'courseValue':
                course = float(elem.text)
                hold['course'] = course
                hold['outbound'] = course + 180 if course + 180 < 360 else course - 180
            elif elem.tag == 'isEnroute':
                hold['type'] = 'ENR'
            elif elem.tag == 'altitude':
                minmax['altitude'] = int(elem.text)
            elif elem.tag == 'hold':
                hold['bottom'] = min['altitude']
                hold['top'] = max['altitude']
                yield hold
```

usage:

```
for hold in xml_fast_iter('test.xml'):
    holdPattern = Avia(**hold)
    prop_dict = holdPattern.__dict__
    print(prop_dict)
```

Note that what I did with `'max'` and `'min'` is nothing but a guess of what you need, but it serves to show how you can work with context data without having to resort to XPath like `./ancestor-or-self::*`, which would be much slower in comparison.

Comment: Wow... really elegant. In case other type of object in xml (e.g. <obstacles>, etc) I have to add a pattern dict in 'start' event and then fill it in 'end'?

Comment: hmm seems that for the other types of objects I need to write its own function - for getting `yield hold`, `yield obstacles`, etc. Objects have completely different keys... Am I right?

Comment: It depends on how your input data is structured. When `obstacles` is a property of the `<hold>` element, it makes sense to build that also as you go, and only do `yield hold` at the end.

Comment: No, `<obstacles>` is not the property of the `<hold>`, This is the same level as `<holds>`

Comment: In this case... hm. If you just want speedy parsing, not doing `yield` and going back to calling `Avia(**hold)` inside the loop would work. If you also want testability (i.e. *"being able to read the XML file without changing anything else"*) I would probably make a `class Hold` and a `class Obstacle`, use them instead of nondescript dicts, and then yield them as and when they come by. Then I would use `for item in xml_fast_iter(...):` in combination with something like `if isinstance(item, Hold):`

Comment: ...but then again, this might be overkill for what you are going for.

Comment: Thank you! I try to implement your idea with the classes (I have ~ 15 types of objects in my XML with their own attributes), so it becomes very readable and easy to debug. Hope it will not overkill my system... Is it really unnecessary to elem.clear() and del ancestor.getparent()[0] as Liza Daly recommend in the paper (link in my question)?

Comment: It's an optimization to save some memory. Before applying it, I would recommend to try both with and without `.clear()` and `del` and measure if it makes noticeable difference in running time or memory consumption. For these kinds of tests, a generator function (with `yield`) is better, because you can factor out all irrelevant stuff and concentrate on parsing performance. Instead of separate classes, a dict property like `'type'` that is different for all item types you expect would also work and save some time on creating those boilerplate classes. It's up to you.